# Is the sequence Cauchy and convergent with the $d_2$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let the space $l^2$ be equipped with its usual metric , $d_2$. Let $x ∈ l^2$ and consider the following sequence $(z_n)^∞_{n=1}$, where

$z_1= x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$

$z_2 = (x_1/2,x_2/2,x_3/2,...)$

$z_3 = (x_1/3,x_2/3,x_3/3,...)$

and so on. Is the sequence Cauchy and convergent?

$d(z_n,z_m) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ (x_i/n-x_i/m)^2}$ $ = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{x_i(m-n)^2}{(nm)^2}}$ $\to 0$ as n, m $\to \infty$

Therefore it is Cauchy

$d(z_n,0) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ (x_i/n)^2}$ $\to 0$ as n $\to \infty$

So it is convergent

is this correct?

Comment: In your argument $d(x_n, x_m)$ and $d(x_n, 0)$ should be replaced by $d(z_n, z_m)$ and $d(z_n, 0)$ respectively. Those two things tend to zero because $x \in \ell^2$ i.e. since $\|x\|_2 \lt \infty.$